# Predictive Analysis Modeling Using Multiple Datasets

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation, predictive-models

I am working on doing some predictive analysis, and we are attempting to implement a schema that we have found in a white paper. I have been searching for a while, but have not been able to come up with a solution to this problem, and am hoping that some of the more experienced Data Scientist of Stack Exchange can point me in the direction of what sort of Data Science techniques one would use to solve this problem.

The paper doesn't go into very much detail, but the schema essentially boils down to the following:

{D_1, D_2, …,D_n} --> {Data Lake} --> {Predictive Modeling} --> {Reporting}

In words, the steps in this process flow are:

Step 1: Start with n data sets D_1,…,D_n

Step 2: Collect the datasets into a Data Lake

Step 3: Use these sources for predictive modeling

Step 4: Report Findings

We have about 10 or so data sets, each which are of different sizes and features. I cannot go into too much detail but, for example, one dataset contains information about company System Uptime and Downtime and another dataset contains information about Customer Complaints about the company in general. We are hoping to gain insights using these 10 datasets by making connections among the various phenomena captured by the datasets.

The reason I am posting this question is that, oversimplifying a little, I am familiar with building Machine Learning models that involves working with a single dataset. The problem described above is different in that it uses multiple datasets. I am interested in what sort of Data Science and modeling techniques would be used to get started on this problem.

The schema also calls for the use of a Data Lake, which we do not have. Would a Data Lake be necessary for this kind of predictive modeling. Our data is all stored in SQL relational databases, and we are hoping that this will be sufficient as a substitute for the Data Lake.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update: Still looking for an answer on this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Bot This problem description has been carefully constructed with as much description as can reasonably be added without violating company policy. It is simply an abstraction of the problem.